# How to optimize bigquery if querying multiple tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table `events_20181001 till events_20181024` which is in format 
`projectname:some_name.events_20181024`, and I am querying specific columns.

If i am taking `_Table_suffix` between `event_20181001` and `event_20181024` the data is approx 14 gb which is huge and cost more. How can I resolve/optimize the query?

the real query looks like this:

```
select date, evname as ev1,ui.value.string_value as k1, upk1.value.string_value as k2, upk.value.string_value as k3 
from `project_name.some_name.*`,
unnest(somejsonkey) as ui,
unnest(somejsonkey) as upk, 
unnest(somejsonkey) as upk1 
where event_name = 'abc' 
and upk1.key = 'def' 
and upk.key ='ghi' 
and ui.key = 'someidentity' 
and _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 'events_20181001' AND 'events_20181024';
```

Comment: do you see any missing option that you ask us to help with? give us a hint! you select only from tables that you need and columns that you want - so how you would see lowering the cost - rather than maybe giving up on some columns and some days/tables?

Comment: Am taking all the tables and then applying filter, is there any option to filter on the go ? Like for table events_20181001 the total size is 1.6 GB and if i query with the single table then its 466 MB. But if am taking all of the tables then its quite huge may be its taking all the data instead of a filtered portion